# Generating different sequences of random numbers for different threads with Mersenne Twister (C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, mersenne-twister

I have a Monte Carlo code and need to run many simulations in parallel using MPI. I would like to be sure that the numbers that are generated in each simulation belong to a different sequence.

Here is a very simple "test" that I wrote but I am not sure if it actually tests what I described.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <random>

int rank;
//std::random_device rd; std::mt19937 mt(rd()) I used this before
std::mt19937 mt(clock()+rank);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);

  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> RandInt(0,100);  
  int xx = RandInt(mt);
  std::cout << rank << ":\t" << xx << "\t" << mt() << std::endl;

  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Executing this program three times gave me:

```
1:  57  3629598283
3:  70  877812043
0:  55  871110422
2:  60  603182895

3:  5   3326625701
2:  72  2574563463
1:  59  1557541786
0:  53  2000448965

0:  16  574716192
1:  53  3847148496
2:  54  3235101660
3:  23  2433046543
```

Does the way that I wrote this program mean that each thread will instantiate each own random generator? Is this safe and guarantees different sequences of numbers? And also, what is the difference, if any, using the commented line `std::random_device rd; std::mt19937 mt(rd())` instead?

**EDIT**

A few more details about the program.

The random numbers in each run are generated both inside `main.cpp` and another file `mclib.cpp`. The random generator is inside a header file `mclib.hpp`.

**main.cpp**

```
#define MAIN
#include "mclib.hpp"
#include <mpi.h> //etc 

int main(){
 MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
 MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);

//choose random point
 std::uniform_int_distribution<int> RandInt(0,100);  
 int xx = RandInt(mt);

//calculate energy differences and check metropolis criterion
// double dE = ... 
bool accept = metropolis(dE);


 MPI_Finalize();
 return 0;
}
```

**mclib.cpp**

```
bool metropolis(double dE){
 std::uniform_int_distribution<double> RandDouble(0,1);
double epsilon = RandDouble(mt);
//compare epsilon with boltzmann factor or accept if dE<0
... 
}
```

**mclib.hpp**

```
#ifdef MAIN
int rank;
std::mt19937 mt(clock()+rank);
#else
extern int rank;
extern std::mt19937 mt;
#endif
```

Do I need to seed twice for each simulation? Once inside the `main.cpp` and another inside `mclib.cpp`?

Comment: `clock()` is _not_ a good seed, as it returns ticks since your program was launched.  Furthermore, you have used `rank` to seed your generator _before_ initializing it with a value.

Comment: If you are concerned about potentially colliding seeds, why not create a program that generates a whole bunch of seeds into a file.  Then remove any duplicates, and choose a specific seed from the file for each individual run.  This way you also get repeatability if you see anomalies that you want to reproduce and debug.

Comment: An alternative might be to generate a random sequence of seeds by the root and then scatter them to all processes. I would likely prefer this approach over reading seed from a file, which forces program users to care about that file availibitily. (Reproducibility may be also easily achieved by using the same seed for generating that sequence of seeds.)

Comment: I edited my question. Can you take a look?

Comment: Also, you may want to search for research articles about parallel random number generation, which often discuss the problem of seeding. Such as: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268160055_On_parallel_random_number_generation_for_accelerating_simulations_of_communication_systems.

Comment: Is it ok if I put inside the main function and after ```MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);```  the line ```std::mt19937 mt(rd()+rank);``` where ```std::random_device rd;```